# Python reads only one char per row from a binary file

Tags: python, binary, binaryfiles

I have a script which 'encodes' user entered text, for now it's just a string 'python' by default. I am having a problem decoding it.

This is the output with f.tell, where I can see it only reads first byte from each row and outputs only 'pto' instead of 'python'.

```
2
p2
2
2
t2
2
2
o2
2
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\file.py", line 73, in <module>
    oa=ord(a)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
>>>
```

Somehow it reads without a problem until string of length 0 is found, I can't found where because text.bin is equally spaced, just like key.bin.

Running xxd -b on text.bin file shows that file contains necessary bytes for decoding.

```
00000000: 00000000 00000000 01110000 00000000 00000000 01111001  ..p..y
00000006: 00000000 00000000 01110100 00000000 00000000 01101000  ..t..h
0000000c: 00000000 00000000 01101111 00000000 00000000 01101110  ..o..n
00000012: 00000000 00000000                                      ..
```

Also key.bin contains them. Here first byte(odd) is an offset between each char in text.bin and second byte (even) is an XOR mask. I set it to 0 because I haven't thought of a method to generate *symetrical* bytes to do xor at the end. I guess I would need XOR cipher for this..

```
00000000: 00000010 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000010 00000000  ......
00000006: 00000010 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000010 00000000  ......
0000000c: 00000010 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000010 00000000  ......
00000012: 00000010 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000010 00000000  ......
00000018: 00000010                                               .
```

Here is the current code

```
fdata = open("text.bin","wb") ; fmeta = open("key.bin","w+b")
print('Enter a text:')
txt='python' # input()
print('Binary:')
print(" ".join(txt))
l=len(txt)
print(l, 'bytes')
strtobin= ' '.join(format(x, 'b') for x in bytearray(txt, 'utf-8'))
print(strtobin)

shift=int(2)
sh=nobv.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')

# even bytes in key.bin
for v in range(0, 25, 2): # len(txt)
    #print(v)
    fmeta.seek(v)
    fmeta.write(sh)

# odd bytes in key.bin (contains first part for XOR)
for a in range(0,25): #len(txt)+1
    if a % 2 != 0:
        #print(a)
        fmeta.seek(a)
        fmeta.write(b'\x00')

pad = b'\x00\00'
for line in txt:
    for char in line:
        fdata.write(pad)
        fdata.write(char.encode())
fdata.write(pad)
fdata.close() ; fmeta.close()

f = open ("key.bin", "rb"); d = open ("text.bin", "rb")
f.seek(0); d.seek(0) ; position = 0
while 1:
        #f.seek(2,0)
        offset = f.read(1)
        f.seek(1,0)
        mask = f.read(1)
        
        if not offset: break;
        if not mask: break;

        shift = int(ord(offset))
        position = position + shift
        d.seek(position)
        
        print(f.tell())
        
        a = d.read(1)
        oa=ord(a)
        om=ord(mask)
        output = chr(oa^om)    
        print (output, end="")
f.close() ; d.close()
```

Comment: Try also printing out `d.tell()`? That's probably the one that's going wrong...

Comment: Also, for more general advice, take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) or a similar resource.

Comment: It prints similar output , just p t o, instead of python, somehow chars y h n are left out of it completely..  `2
p4
6
8
t10
12
14
o16
18
20`

Comment: Right, so now you know what it's doing, you can start to figure out why it's reading those positions (which have NUL characters) and not the ones that have the letters y, h and n.

Comment: Yeah I found it. The problem was that I couldn't write an int(2) as a binary somehow, it works with int(1) though.  `int(2).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')`. I needed to write a byte for a decimal 2, but I can only write for 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your script looked like something I could help with, so I thought I'd give it the old college try.

First problem is at line 15: you didn't define "sh"; also, the way you wrote your "in range" block will not work on a lot of systems, so I made it look more like your other loop.

```
for v in range(0, 25):
    if v % 2 == 0:
        #print(v)
        fmeta.seek(v)
        fmeta.write(sh)
```

I'm not sure what you're using that variable for, specifically, so I just added the line
`sh = b'\x01'`
to the list of variables at the top while I as testing the script.  Figure it'd make it easy to spot what the script is actually doing, later.

Now, at this point, I get the error

```
oa=ord(a)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

I suspect the issue is with these two lines:
38: `offset = f.read(1)` , and
45: `shift = int(ord(offset))`

Your program is reading the offset from your file "key.bin", and then stepping that far over into the file "text.bin", and when it goes to `a =  d.read(1)`, sometimes it's reading EOF or a null value.

I'm not entirely sure how to fix the script, here, because I don't understand what your goal output is, but I hope I was able to help, anyway :)

Comment: Thanks. I somehow left out variable 'sh', but I had it
`sh1=int(2)
sh=sh1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')` It writes in even byte places integer 2 - the amount necessary to shift pointer after each character is written.

Goal output was to get original input string 'python'
It is being found after doing an XOR between 0 bytes and a byte for each character.